# How do I check if more than one record has been returned from DBI query in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, count, dbi

I searched for this on the site already but couldn't locate anything that answered my question. Which brings me to the details:

I am querying database using a simple select query, realistically (given the scenario) it should never return more than about 5 to 6 records. I just want to check if more than one has been returned. And if more than one has been return act upon that (in an else statement) if only one has been returned then I progress with the script.

```
my $sql = qq { SELECT col1, col2, col3
                 FROM table
            WHERE col1 = 'foo'
          };

my $sth = $dbc->prepare_cached($sql) or die "Could not prepare statement: " . $dbc->errstr;

$sth->execute() or die "Could not execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

# Not sure how to efficiently check for more than one row returned and still progress if true... This is my problem! I'm thinking a nested if to see if any rows were returned, and then progress with the check of one or more rows? But how can this me checked (like a count function?)
if (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {

 # One row was returned...

} else {
 # More than one row was returned... Uh oh!
}
```

If you guys know of a thread that I couldn't locate that answers this question simply redirect my and I'll nullify this thread!

Regards,
BorisTheBulletDodger!

Comment: What work will you do in the else when more than one row is returned?

Comment: I will log an error stating that duplicate rows exist for this query.

Answer (score 6):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tablename");
$sth->execute();
my $rows = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
if (@$rows == 0) {
    die "no rows returned";
} elsif (@$rows > 1) {
    die "too many rows returned";
}
my $row = $rows->[0];
print "col1 is $row->{col1}\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for this one Chas, quick question though!

What would happen if no rows were returned? I am trying to log one particular error if no rows were returned, another (different) error if more than one row was returned, or else just progress with the script as only one row was returned. This just handles if there is a second row! (Still... this is a very good solution)

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, point, it would die with "too many rows", let me fix that.

Comment: I am having a problem actually counting the rows here. The $rows property appears to return a "ARRAY(0x1ae2a6c)" value.

I've tried numerous method to retrieve  value but none appear to be successful.

Thanks

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I had mistyped!

Solutions works perfect.

Answer (score 5):

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare();
$sth->execute();

my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
my $second = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();

if ($second) {
  print "2+ rows\n";
} elsif ($row) {
  print "1 row\n";
} else {
  print "no rows\n";
}
```

Comment: This was the route I was thinking of initially. I think this suffices!

Comment: Tried this, this simply reselects and populates the same row into $second as it did to $row.

This currently doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to authoritatively determine whether more than one row has been found by a `SELECT` is to try to retrieve more than one row.  DBI does provide the `->rows` property, but it is only guaranteed to work for non-`SELECT` statements.

The answers to [How can I check if a database query will return results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290133/how-can-i-check-if-a-database-query-will-return-results) may also prove useful, even though it's not quite the same question.

Comment: Thanks for that link Dave. As insightful as it was, this guy appears to be focusing on on getting some data or none! whereas I am focusing on getting no data or one (record), if more than one is returned then execute the 'uh oh!' section!

I do think there is a limitation in DBI that doesn't provide a count feature on select statemants. Even if it is only a partial count.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the `fetchall_*` or `selectall_*` methods (see the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.607/DBI.pm)), since you'll only have 5-6 at most.  Then determine how many rows you got after all.